# Variables, propiedades y elementos de una clase

Tags: c#

Ha llegado a mis manos un código el cual contenía una estructura similar a esta:

```
public class Cosa
{
    public string elemento;
    public string elementoDos {get; set;}
}
```

Hasta entonces yo siempre he declarado propiedades con get, set o ambos, pero nunca me había topado con una declaración sin estos, preguntando e investigando al respecto he averiguado que `elemento` es una variable y `elementoDos` una propiedad.

Me saltan dudas sobre como actúan estos dos tipos a la hora de declararlos y de trabajar con ellos

- ¿`elemento` es invocable?
- ¿Puedo introducirle un valor?
- ¿Cuáles son sus diferencias?
- ¿En que puede fallar la variable o la propiedad?
- ¿Dónde está la documentación al respecto?
- ¿Cuándo es mas adecuado usar una u otra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahora es cuando voy a liarte mas :)

En realidad, `elemento` no es una variable, es un [campo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields):

> Un campo es una variable de cualquier tipo que se declara directamente
> en una clase o struct. Los campos son miembros de su tipo contenedor.

- ¿`elemento` es invocable?

Claro. Es miembro de la clase, y al ser declarado como `public` puedes acceder al mismo desde otras clases.

- ¿Puedo introducirle un valor?

Por supuesto, no deja de ser una variable

- ¿Cuáles son sus diferencias?

Hay varias diferencias. Pero básicamente las propiedades no son variables, son en realidad un *syntax sugar* para definir dos métodos, `get` y `set`, muy similares a los getters y setters de java. Además, las propiedades siempre tienen una variable donde realmente se almacenan los datos. Su sentido principal es uno muy sencillo: tener un control sobre los datos introducidos/leídos en una variable. Un ejemplo muy sencillo: imaginemos que queremos limitar el valor máximo que adquiere una variable entera. Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, pero una muy elegante es usar propiedades y validar los datos en el setter. Algo asi:

```
private int _propiedad;
public int Propiedad {
    get
    {
        return this._propiedad;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value<100000)
        { 
             this._propiedad=value;
        }
    }
```

De esta forma tan sencilla y elegante, validamos que en `Propiedad` nunca haya un valor mayor a 100000, da igual desde que lugar del código intentemos modificar este valor.

- ¿En que puede fallar la variable o la propiedad?

No se que responder a esto. Puede fallar en lo mismo que una variable normal.

- ¿Dónde está la documentación al respecto?

[Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/properties) tienes la documentación sobre las propiedades, la de los campos ya la enlacé anteriormente.

- ¿Cuándo es mas adecuado usar una u otra?

En general, yo tiendo a usar Propiedades en el 99% de los casos, sobre todo si van a ser accedidas desde otra clase. Los campos en realidad deberían ser privados y usarse únicamente para almacenamiento interno de la clase. Esta es mi forma de actuar, no se si realmente hay alguna directiva mas "oficial" sobre el tema.